# Need a way to convert a single string in docker args to many args

Tags: docker, go, github-actions

I coded a small Golang program, that takes N arguments (files with resourceQuota requests for K8s) from a GitHub PR, and writes a file with the total amount of CPU and Memory requested that is then exported as GHA output in the next step.

can't do `go run main.go /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2` because Apparently i hit a  bug in `actions/setup-go` with our self-hosted runner, so i had to containerise that.

I'm new to all of these, so my colleagues told me to import the docker program from a self-made GitHub action, all works like a charm when only 1 file is changed in the PR (only 1 arg to handle).

Problem is when 2 or more args are passed, because the action im using: [tj-actions/changed-files](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/changed-files) outputs a single string with all the files names and i'm really clueless on how to work around it.

this is how i call the self-made action:

```
      - name: Capture request values actions
        uses: ./goCapacityCheck
        with:
          files: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}
```

goCapacityCheck action.yml

```
name: 'goCapacityCheck'
description: 'Capture requests CPU and Memory values from all files in the PR'
inputs:
  files:
    description: 'files changed in the PR.'
    required: false

runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: './Dockerfile'
  args:
    - ${{ inputs.files }}
```

is there a way to split that string when passing to the action? or to Docker or something?

I haven't tried much when i hit this issue, but i'd expect that the sting that looks like `"/path/to/file1 /path/to/file2"` to be split at some point in order to be able to do
`docker run --name mygocap gocap /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to handle it inside the go program because i would never now how many arguments would come in, so from `os.Args[]` i called `getFileNames()` and then i did the rest of the routine with `filenames` instead of `os.Args[1:]` directly.

```
func main() {
    filenames := getFileNames(os.Args[1:]) {
    for _, file := range filenames {
        // handling of the file data
        fmt.Println(file)
}
    
func getFileNames(s []string) []string {
    var filenames []string
    for _, file := range s {
        if strings.Contains(file, " ") {
            filenames = append(filenames, strings.Split(file, " ")...)
        } else {
            filenames = append(filenames, file)
        }
    }
    return filenames
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split with some bash tricks, as example:

```
string="/path/to/file1 /path/to/file2"
echo \"$(echo $string | cut -d' ' -f1)\" \"$(echo $string | cut -d' ' -f2)\"
```

will print

```
"/path/to/file1" "/path/to/file2"
```

So you could try something like this in a GitHub action workflow:

```
      - name: run
        run: |
          string=${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}
          first=$(echo $string | cut -d' ' -f1)
          second=$(echo $string | cut -d' ' -f2)
          docker run --name mygocap gocap $first $second
```

Comment: a few issues with your approach: 
- i mentioned the program takes N arguments (2 was just for illustration) 
- i'm not running the docker image from the workflow, but calling a self-made action, hence i can't do `docker run --name mygocap gocap $first $second` 

thanks for your contribution.